# Android Animation From Middle Of The Screen to Top And Out Of View?

Tags: android, xml, animation

I have been trying to find the answer but, have had no success. I need the XML for the animation if the Activity is currently on in the middle of the screen, and for it to slide up and out of view.

Any help would be greatly appretiated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand what you want correctly, I think you should try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
```

Comment: Sorry then it's fromYDelta="100%" toYDelta="0%"